# AlarmManager: shorter intervals for testing

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I know that in production devices `AlarmManager` cannot be triggered more often than 1/minute. This is fine, but for testing I would like to have a short time.

```
 manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 10000, 60000, pendingIntent)
```

Is there some workaround? What is the recommended procedure to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices will not trigger repeating alarms with intervals of less than about 1 to 2 minutes (some devices have more strict rules). If you want to have alarms triggered more often, you must use a single (non-repeating) alarm, use `setExact()` when possible, and then when the alarm goes off, you set the next one. In this way you can get much shorter intervals with more precise timing.

Answer (score 1):

In normal way you don't have to test the broadcast receiver. (If I know right. If I don't, pls edit it!)

You should test the functions of your activity/class which should appear.
You can do it in this way:

```
@get:Rule
val rule = ActivityTestRule(YourActivity::class.java)
```

This will start your (the given) activity, and now you can test your functions.

(More options for start an activity/intent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61082715/11211963 )