# How to use ActivityTestRule when launching activity with bundle?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am using

```
  val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(SingleFragmentActivity::class.java, true, true)
```

and SingleFragmentActivity is a test helper activity class I used from google GithubBrowseSample

how can I launch activity with bundle ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#getactivityintent. can you not use getActivityIntent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get activity from activityRule and you can set extra data for intent

```
activityRule.activity.intent.putExtra("key",value)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use an Intent instead of passing a Bundle?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways of achieve what you would like to. First one, unfortunately, require creating custom `ActivityRule`, which will override some method.

- [`ActivityTestRule.html#getActivityIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#getActivityIntent())

The second approach doesn't require overriding `ActivityRule`:

- [`ActivityTestRule.html#launchActivity(android.content.Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#launchActivity(android.content.Intent))

but it requires passing `false` as a third parameter of `ActivityRule` constructor (`launchActivity = false`). In your case:

```
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(SingleFragmentActivity::class.java, true, false)
```

I'd suggest the using the second approach, as then intent can be easily passed to `ActivityRule` but requires to start activity manually at test startup:

```
activityRule.launchActivity(
    Intent(context, SingleFragmentActivity::class.java).apply {
        /*put arguments */
    }
)
```

Comment: the doc has been deprecaded. For androidx, plz refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 option. 
First: if you want the same intent (e.g. with the same extras) in every test.

```
    @get:Rule
    var rule: ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> =
        object : ActivityTestRule<YourActivity>(YourActivity::class.java) {
            override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent {
                val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
                return Intent(targetContext, YourActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("someString","string")
                    putExtra("someBoolean",true)
               }
            }
         }
```

Second: if you want different intent (e.g. with different extras) in every test:

```
    @get:Rule
    val rule = ActivityTestRule(YourActivity::class.java,
    true,
    false) // launch activity later -> if its true, the activity will start here

    @Test
    fun testFunction(){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("name",value)
        intent.putExtra("someBoolean",false)
        rule.launchActivity(intent)
    }
```

source: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-21-activitytestrule.html

Comment: Is it launch different activity from Test method? If yes how ?